# ActionListener not resolved on VSCode

Tags: java, swing, visual-studio-code

I'm getting into JFrame.

I'm trying to implement *ActionListener* but my VSCode keeps saying "type cant't resolve" and either change it into *AncestorListener* or *Create an ActionListener Class*.

So I thought it maybe the complier and extensions are messing with it (I have alot of extension on VSC). I changed to IJ and it worked there is *ActionListener* working.

So now I thought about the versions (I have two versions 8 and 16). I changed the versions on IJ and *ActionListener* would still work on IJ.

So I when back to VSCode, uninstalled the un-needed extensions and changed the versions, It still won't work. I changed it to *Action* class and so far so good.

Afterwhich, I restart my machine, restart VSCode it suddenly have ActionListener now, I changed the versions of Java and it still work on VSCode. Re-installed all the extensions and *ActionListener* still worked.

Now I'm wondering what happened, is it because i changed the versions so quickly VSCode doesn't update fast enough or there is something else *(I'm sorry for the wording if it is not clear and I'm sorry if there is no pictures or code)*

Comment: Just an FYI. Netbeans, IntelliJ & Eclipse are all free to download and use. It's likely all three will run Java code effortlessly, and in case there is a problem, there will be far more people willing & able to help.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same message in vs code but importing `java.awt.event.ActionListener` should work.